# A rational distance problem with (possibly) multiple solutions

Tags: discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, diophantine-geometry

**Background:** It is not known if any point exists on the XY plane that is at rational distance from all 4 vertices of a unit square lying on the XY plane ([https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalDistanceProblem.html#:~:text=The%20rational%20distance%20problem%20asks,can%20be%20cleared%20by%20multiplication](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalDistanceProblem.html#:%7E:text=The%20rational%20distance%20problem%20asks,can%20be%20cleared%20by%20multiplication)).

However, it is trivial to find other quadrilaterals with such a point - indeed, the points (3,0), (0,4), (-3,0), (0,-4) form a quad (a rhombus) with all sides of length 5 and the origin is at rational distances from all its vertices. The points (15,0), (0,25), (-48,0) and (0, -36) form a quadrilateral with all side lengths different integers and all 4 vertices at integer distances from origin; and the line segments from the origin to the vertices cut the quad into 4 mutually unequal right triangles.

**Question:** Is there a quadrilateral Q with (1) all 4 vertices having rational coordinates, (2) edges having rational lengths and (3) *more than one point P* on the plane has all distances from the 4 vertices rational? Does insisting that the coordinates of the P's are also rational have an impact on the question? If for some Q, more than one such P can be found, is there an upper bound on the number of such special P's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known that there are infinite sets $S$ of points on the unit circle
with rational coordinates and rational distances.  So we can take any
four points of $S$, make them the vertices of $Q$, and get infinitely many
other points $P \in S$ at rational distances from all four vertices of $Q$.

Explicitly, let
$$
S = \{ z^2 : z \in {\bf Q}(i), \, z \bar z = 1 \}, 
$$
which is infinite because there are infinitely many primitive Pythagorean triples
$(a,b,c)$ and each yields $z = (a+bi)/c$ with $z \bar z = 1$.
The distance between any two points $w^2,z^2 \in S$ is
$$
|w^2 - z^2| = \left| wz \left(w/z - z/w\right) \right|
= \left|w\right| \left|z\right| \left| (w/z) - (w/z)^{-1} \right|,
$$
and $|w| = |z| = 1$, while $(w/z)^{-1} = \overline{w/z}$ so
$$
\left| (w/z) - (w/z)^{-1} \right|
= | w/z - \overline{w/z} \, |
= \left| 2i \, {\rm Im}(w/z) \right|
= 2 \, {\rm Im} (w/z) \in {\bf Q}, 
$$
**QED**.

For example, starting from the 3,4,5 triangle and scaling by 25 we find that the rectangle with vertices $(\pm 7, \pm 24)$ has all sides and both diagonals rational, and there are infinitely points on its circumcircle $x^2 + y^2 = 25^2$ at rational distances from all four vertices, starting with $(x,y) = (\pm 25, 0)$.

It is harder to find cases with infinitely many $P$ in the *interior* of the quadrilateral.  (The above construction does give one such $P$, namely the center of the circle.)

Comment: Nice! From the last remark, I understand you think that there should be quads for which there are indeed infinitely many 'P points' that lie in the interior. And pushing the envelope, one could wonder if there are quads for which there are P points that are farther than any finite distance d! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  On further thought, if Q is symmetrical about 
a diagonal D of rational length then there are infinitely many "P points" on D
$-$ this again comes down to the infinitude of primitive Pythagorean triples.
So we get points in the interior and also arbitrarily far.  
If D has rational length but is not a symmetry axis then we usually stll
get infinitely many "P points" on D because they're parametrized by
an elliptic curve with a few rational points.  Alas a unit square is
symmetrical about its diagonals but they do not have rational length so this simple approach fails.

Answer (score 2):

The rectangle with vertices $(\pm60,\pm15)$ has rational distances from the corners to both $(\pm52,0)$, because both $(15,8,17)$ and $(15,112,113)$ are Pythagorean triples.

Answer (score 2):

You should consult my joint paper with Andrew Bremner: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X15002243
concernig points at rational distances from the vertices of certain geometric objects. In particular, as one of several results, we prove that the set of positive rational numbers $a$ such that there exist infinitely many rational points in the plane which lie at rational distance from the four vertices of the rectangle with vertices $(0, 0), (0, 1), (a, 0), (a, 1)$ is dense in the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer